# reading from big csv file and save rows which meet condition into another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, memory, chunks

I have a big csv file (dataset) with size 443,00 KB. The photo shows a sample of the file. I want save rows  into another dataframe. I tried this way, but it is taking so much time e

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv("UsersVle.csv", chunksize=10):
    for i, row in chunk.iterrows():
        if((row['module']=='D3') & (row['presentation']=='13B')):
            df.append(row)
```

Searching for a solution, I found something about chuncksize and tried it this way , but there was error TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

```
import itertools as IT

chunksize = 10 ** 3
chunks = pd.read_csv('UsersVle.csv', chunksize=chunksize)
chunks = IT.takewhile(lambda chunk: (chunk['module']=='D3' & chunk['presentation']=='13B'), chunks)
df = pd.concat(chunks)
```

I need an efficient way to read from this big file and save the rows meeting the condition into another dataframe. I will appreciate your help. PS, I tried dask, but it seems did not read the file as I used df.head(), the were no returned rows !.
[image]

Comment: I think you need to find the right value for the chunksize. 10 or 1000 are too low values for me when tried via movie dataset (ratings.csv). The optimal for me was 10**6.

Answer (score 1):

Not very scientific, but something to get an idea to adjust the value:

Using [moviedataset/rating.csv](https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/moviedataset.zip):

```
print('Without chunksize')
start = timer()
df = pd.read_csv('ml-latest/ratings.csv')
df2 = df[df["rating"] == 5.0]
print(timer() - start)

for cs in range(4, 10):
    print('Chunk size', cs, 10 ** cs)
    start = timer()
    rdr= pd.read_csv('ml-latest/ratings.csv', chunksize=10**cs)
    df2 = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['rating'] == 5.0] for chunk in rdr])
    print(timer() - start)
```

Output:

```
Without chunksize
5.055990324995946
Chunk size 4 10000
8.80516574899957
Chunk size 5 100000
5.21452364900324
Chunk size 6 1000000
4.814042658996186
Chunk size 7 10000000
4.8958623920043465
Chunk size 8 100000000
5.152557591005461
Chunk size 9 1000000000
5.076704847000656
```